# Printing Variable results in blank line

Tags: c, structure, c99

After returning a structure with all information from a parsed file, all data members are being printed as blank lines except the one data member in the structure that is not a pointer. I think this is a problem with handling pointers but I am not sure. For example, I set a char * in the structure equal to the name in the file. Right after setting the variable, I will print it out and the name is correct, but once I return the pointer to the struct, or once I am outside of the while loop that reads the file, a blank line is printed when I try to print the name. Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE 10
#define _MAX_SIZE 80

typedef struct Map_s{

        char * defender;
        char * attacker;
        int missles;
        int ** layout;
        size_t capacity;
        size_t size;

}map;
```

The first snippet of code shows what file headers I included, along with the structure that will be used.

```
map * newGame(){

        map * game = malloc(sizeof(map));
        game->layout = (int**)malloc(_DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE * sizeof(int*));
        game->defender = NULL;
        game->attacker = NULL;
        game->missles = 0;
        game->capacity = _DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
        game->size = 0;

        return game;
}
```

Function to initialize a new structure type

```
map * parseFile( FILE * fp ){

        map * game = newGame();

        char * token;
        const char delim[2] = " ";
        char * buf = NULL;
        char * temp = NULL;
        size_t size = _MAX_SIZE;
        int lineNum = 1;

        while( getline(&temp, &size, fp) > 1 ){
                buf = strtok(temp, "\n");
                //printf("%s\n", buf);
                if( buf[0] != '#' ){
                        printf("%s\n", buf);
                        printf("%d\n", lineNum);
                        if( lineNum == 1){
                                if( game->defender == NULL ){
                                        game->defender = buf;
                                }
                        }
                        else if( lineNum == 2 ){
                                if( game->attacker == NULL )
                                        game->attacker = buf;
                        }
                        else if( lineNum == 3 ){
                                game->missles = atoi(buf);
                        }
                        else if( lineNum > 3 ){
                                token = strtok(buf, delim);

                                while( token != NULL ){
                                        if( game->size >= game->capacity ){
                                                game->layout = (int**)realloc(game->layout, \
                                                                game->capacity*2 * sizeof(int*));
                                                game->capacity = game->capacity * 2;
                                        }

                                        game->layout[game->size] = (int*)token;
                                        game->size = game->size + 1;
                                        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                }
                        }

                        lineNum++;
                }

        }

        return game;

}
```

This code parses the file. Any line starting with a '#' is a comment and will not be used. The first two lines of the file are names, the third line is a number, and any line after that will be ten integers with a newline character at the end.

Comment: `game->defender = buf` does ***not*** make a copy of the string that `buf` points to. You need to allocate memory (e.g. `malloc`), and copy the string (e.g. `strcpy`).

Comment: @user3386109 thank you. Could I use strdup() and free it after each line?

Comment: Yes, you can use `strdup`. But you don't want to `free` the string that `strdup` returns until the program is done with the string, e.g. when the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing address of read buffer to 'map' structure whose content will be updated every `getline()` call. You can fix this by doing following changes

```
while( getline(&temp, &size, fp) > 1 ){
                buf = strtok(temp, "\n");
                //printf("%s\n", buf);
                if( buf[0] != '#' ){
                        printf("%s\n", buf);
                        printf("%d\n", lineNum);
                        if( lineNum == 1){
                                if( game->defender == NULL ){
                                        line_end = strchrnul(buf,'\n');
                                        line_size = line_end - buf;
                                        game->defender = malloc(line_size + 1);
                                        strncpy(game->defender,buf,line_size;
                                }
                        }
                        else if( lineNum == 2 ){
                                if( game->attacker == NULL ) {
                                        line_end = strchrnul(buf,'\n');
                                        line_size = line_end - buf;
                                        game->attacker = malloc(line_size + 1);
                                        strncpy(game->attacker,buf,line_size;
                                }
                        }
                        else if( lineNum == 3 ){
                                game->missles = atoi(buf);
                        }
                        else if( lineNum > 3 ){
                                token = strtok(buf, delim);

                                while( token != NULL ){
                                        if( game->size >= game->capacity ){
                                                game->layout = (int**)realloc(game->layout, \
                                                                game->capacity*2 * sizeof(int*));
                                                game->capacity = game->capacity * 2;
                                        }

                                        game->layout[game->size] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                                        *game->layout[game->size] = *(int*)token;
                                        game->size = game->size + 1;
                                        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                }
                        }

                        lineNum++;
                }

        }
```